# hole in roof of oven

Tags: oven, hole, rust

**Oven type:** Siemens, BUILT-IN/BUILT-UNDER COOKER/OVEN HB90355GB

**Problem:** In the top mini-oven, above the grill element, a metal plate (liner-catalytic) has fallen off because the screw holding it in place has rusted out. The holes for the screw, both in the metal plate and in the oven are damaged. There is another big hole further back in the roof of the oven, which looks like it could have taken a screw, but I can't find any evidence of a screw (i.e. no pieces of remaining screw). I think this back hole is actually a venting hole. The damage to where the screw goes was likely caused by condensation in the oven and insufficient cleaning leading to a rust problem.

**Queries:**

1. Any advice on how I could secure a new metal plate (liner-catalytic) to the roof of the oven safely?
2. Is it a problem that the venting hole (at the back) is rusted and bending upward?
3. Do I need to consider some other form of solution other than securing a new metal plate? (i.e. replacing the oven?)

**Additional information:**

In the pictures: you can see the part number for the metal plate (296335) and the screw that would hold the plate in place (418562). You can also see where the damage is.

Advice welcome. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the "rusted hole" from the other side of the panel?  Anything wrong with using a bigger screw?

Comment: Thanks @Huesmann. I've not tried taking the oven out just yet. There is an outer panel and a bunch of insulation (fire retardant material) I suspect on the outside. Not sure how much fiddling I want to do without entirely knowing what I am doing. But, yes, a bigger screw seems a sensible / simple option for now. Any thoughts / concerns on using a regular screw? Would I need to consider some "temperature proof" screw of sorts? Thank you!

Comment: I have not seen anything regarding a need for temperature proofing oven screws.  I *would* recommend stainless, just because you never know what food might spatter on it, and cooking also produces steam, i.e. water.